# Unity and Swift Colliding when using ARKit

Tags: swift, arkit, xcode10

I am using Xcode 10. I am using Unity with my app, I render a view with Unity content and it worked fine until the aspect ratios of iPhone plus sizes and now iPhone XS Max, XR etc.. The problem is the unity view doesn't show in fullscreen, it repeats itself weirdly. As you can see in the picture below. I have constrained this view to the top and bottom. Also applied Equal-Width and Equal-Height constraints on this view with superview. Any guesses why this is happening?

[image]